# Usage of SVR in Non Stationary Time Series Forecasting

Tags: regression, time-series, python, forecasting, svm

Based on my knowledge of Support Vector Regression(SVR), One of the assumptions of SVR are

1. Independent Identical Distribution.

So the application of SVR in forecasting of **non-stationary Time series** makes sense? As the properties of non-stationary is in violation of the basic assumptions of SVR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition of **independent identical distributions** (iid) refers to the $(x,y)$ data points. Independence means:
$$
p((x_i, y_i), (x_k, y_k)) = p((x_i, y_i)) p((x_k, y_k)),
$$
i.e. the sampling of $(x_i, y_i)$ doesn't give us any information about the sampling of $(x_k, y_k)$, given the distribution.

And the identical distribution part says, that $(x_i, y_i)$ and $(x_k, y_k)$ have been sampled from the same distribution.

On the other hand, the **stationarity requirement** in time series, where the $x_i$ are just consecutive integers, is referring to the mean and autocovariance of the $y$ values, requiring those to be constant. In particular, $y_i$ and $y_k$ can still be dependent, as long as this dependence doesn't change.

Thus, both non-stationary and stationary time series (usually) violate the iid requirement.

Comment: If it violates the assumptions, Then it doesn't make sense to use SVR for this problem. Is that understanding right?

Comment: You would have to describe how exactly you want to apply SVR.